# Populating an ASP.Net Drop Down List with DataSet data from DataSet created with DataSet designer

Tags: asp.net, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset, populate, html-select

We have an ASP.Net / VB.Net web form containing a drop down list in the markup of the aspx file. There is also a DataSet created with the DataSet designer.

We would like to populate the drop down with data from the DataSet.

Can you show me some sample markup and / or VB.Net coding that is required to populate the drop down list with the DataSet data?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="MyDropDownList" runat="server" DataTextField="SomeString" DataValueField="SomeUniqueId" />
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myDataSet = new DataSet(); // replace with your dataset
    MyDropDownList.DataSource = myDataSet;
    MyDropDownList.DataBind();
}
```

VB.Net:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim aDataSet As DataSet
    MyDropDownList.DataSource = aDataSet
    MyDropDownList.DataBind()
End Sub
```

And you see the "DataTextField" and "DataValueField" in the markup? There's where you put the name of fields you want to use as id (data value) and to display (data text) in the drop-down list.

Here's an example:

### Markup

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            Fruits
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListWithFruits" runat="server" DataTextField="FruitName" DataValueField="FruitId" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

### Code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myDataSet = new DataSet();
    var table1 = new DataTable();
    table1.Columns.Add("FruitName");
    table1.Columns.Add("FruitId");
    table1.Rows.Add("Apple", 1);
    table1.Rows.Add("Banana", 2);
    table1.Rows.Add("Grapefruit", 3);

    myDataSet.Tables.Add(table1);

    DropDownListWithFruits.DataSource = myDataSet;
    DropDownListWithFruits.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the helpful replies. I will be trying this one today. :-)

Comment: This would display System.Data.DataRowView for every row!

Comment: @bleemboy what are you on about? It will not. Please do not downvote when you are the one who's wrong.

See my updated (working) code example.

Answer (score 2):

ComboboxName.DataSource =YourDataSetName

ComboboxName.DataValueField =Name OF the field that you want to return its selected value

for example "ID"

ComboboxName.DataTextField =Name OF the field that you want to view in the drop down list

for example "Name"

ComboboxName.DataBind()